# packages not available when importing in sudo python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

So I am using pip through conda to install packages for python3. One package in particular, called keyboard i am running into issues with.

Specifically, If I write:

```
>import keyboard
>keyboard.wait('s')
```

I run into: `ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.`

However, if i try to run it with admin privelages opening python3 with: `sudo python3` I run into the problem:

```
> import keyboard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

Somehow the package is not recognised anymore. what is happening?

Comment: Does the command which python give you the same result on both cases?

Comment: Hint: which python, then sudo su;which python, if they are different you can tell sudo's python does not have the package installed, therefore, sudo su then install the package, either with pip or whatever.
Though I would suggest a virtualenv BUT do whatever you want at your own risk

Comment: `which python3` and `sudo which python3`.

Comment: a virtualenv would solve all that crap sudo su; source venv/bin/activate;python whatever